# How to use GD enhancer to resize an image in uploading process

Tags: php, html, image, image-processing, pdo

I want to do is to resize the the image that i will be moving to upload folder using GD enhancer in my image upload script.

My problem is after i try the GD enhancer in my php code i couldn't make it work.

my current php code:

```
<?php
include_once('../dbc/database.php');

$db = new Connection();
$db = $db->dbConnect();
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
use gdenhancer\GDEnhancer;
include_once 'GDEnhancer.php';

$emailCodeResult = isset($_POST['emailCodeResult']) ? $_POST['emailCodeResult'] : "";

$imageLink = isset($_POST['imageLink']) ? $_POST['imageLink'] : "";
const path = "files/upload/";
$s= explode(path,$imageLink);
unlink("../upload/".$s[1]);

$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : "";

$type = $_FILES["imageInput"]["type"];
$ext = end(explode('/', $type));
$filename = uniqid() . '_' .$emailCodeResult . '.' . $ext; 
$image = new GDEnhancer($filename);
$image->backgroundResize(300, 300, 'shrink');
$save = $image->save();
header('content-type:' . $save['mime']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imageInput"]["tmp_name"], "../upload/" . $save);
$location = "files/upload/" . $filename;

if(!empty($_POST['email'])) {

        $q = "UPDATE tbl_user SET user_image = '$location' WHERE user_email= :email ";
        $query = $db->prepare($q);
        $query->bindParam(':email', $email);
        $results = $query->execute();
        echo "1";

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, check this [link](http://www.gdenhancer.com/index.php?content=methods&method=save) (example #1 Save image to folder)

Second, you don't have to check image type, GDEnhancer will do this for you.

Third, `header('content-type:' . $save['mime'])` is not necessary if you save file to disk.